# How to Add a Left Margin to TableView Section Headers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I would like to add a left margin to my TableView Section Headers (i.e. space between the left edge and the section header).

[image]

I'm adding the section headers with the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    switch section {
    case 0:
        label.text = "Section Header 1"
    case 1:
        label.text = "Section Header 2"
    case 2:
        label.text = "Section Header 3"
    case 3:
        label.text = "Section Header 4"
    default:
        label.text = nil
    }
    return label
}
```

I've added a `.contentInset` to accomplish similar in other components, but I don't think that works here. Is there something I can add to the `label` property to implement a left margin?

Comment: Are you doing it programmatically or through interface builder, because the answer deepens on that.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: `var spacer = "     "` and add this spacer right after creating your label instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one extra view and adjust the frame.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width - (20 * 2), height: sectionView.bounds.height))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    switch section {
    case 0:
        label.text = "Section Header 1"
    case 1:
        label.text = "Section Header 2"
    case 2:
        label.text = "Section Header 3"
    case 3:
        label.text = "Section Header 4"
    default:
        label.text = nil
    }
    
    sectionView.addSubview(label)
    return sectionView
}
```

Comment: setting the height of label to sectionView.bounds.height didnt work for me, as the height was then zero. I had to set the height to a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the Indent and no extra view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20
    let content: String
    switch section {
    case 0:
        content = "Section Header 1"
    case 1:
        content = "Section Header 2"
    case 2:
        content = "Section Header 3"
    case 3:
        content = "Section Header 4"
    default:
        content = ""
    }
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: content, attributes: [.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle, .backgroundColor: UIColor.white])
    label.attributedText = attributedString
    return label
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Super helpful!